# configChanges work in android 4 and 2.2?

Tags: android

i didn't found the solution, so i ask it. 
I don't want refresh activity when i rotate mobile to landscape, so i need put in AndroidManifest.xml inside the activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

I set in `Project properties -> Android -> Project Build Target -> Android 4.4`
it works for API 13 and higher, but i want API 8 too (android 2.2), because my project is API 8 to API 19. 
if i try run project with avd 4.3 setting for example, it works fine.
if i try run project with avd 2.2 it does not work.
if i put only `android:configChanges="orientation"` it works only in avd 2.2 but not in 4.3

what do I need to do? 2 version? or is there a solution?
thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
```