# Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46029dd0

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am developing an feedback kind of application, when I click the "submitnow" button      I am getting the following error

Activity has leaked window

```
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46029dd0
```

Following is my code, please help me out.

```
public class SignOut_Activity extends SherlockActivity implements
        OnClickListener {

    Button btnSubmitNow, btnSubmitLater;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.signout);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle))
                .setText(StoresListAdapter.StoreName);

        btnSubmitNow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitNow);
        btnSubmitLater = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitLater);

        btnSubmitNow.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSubmitLater.setOnClickListener(this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignOut_Activity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading data, please wait...");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; finish activity to go home
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sign Out");

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSubmitNow:
            // Submit now

            // Sample upload image
            UploadImage.uploadImage("testimage");

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                // called before execution // main/UI thread
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    progressDialog.show();
                };

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Submit the store data
                    StoreData.postData(StoreList_Activity.storesList
                            .get(StoresListAdapter.Position));
                    return null;
                }

                // on store data uploaded // main/UI thread
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    setSignOut();
                    StoreList_Activity.storesList
                            .get(StoresListAdapter.Position).isSubmitted = true;
                    SignOut_Activity.this.finish();
                };

            }.execute();

            break;
        case R.id.btnSubmitLater:
            // Submit later
            setSignOut();
            StoreList_Activity.storesList.get(StoresListAdapter.Position).isSubmitLater = true;
            VisitOps_Activity.isSubmitLater = true;
            SignOut_Activity.this.finish();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void setSignOut() {

        VisitOp visitOp10 = new VisitOp();
        visitOp10.setName("Sign Out");
        visitOp10.setStatus("");
        SampleData.visitOpsList.add(visitOp10);

        if (VisitOps_Activity.VisitOps.SignOut == null)
            VisitOps_Activity.VisitOps.SignOut = new SignOut();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        VisitOps_Activity.VisitOps.SignOut.SignOutTime = "Out: "
                + currentDateandTime;

    }
}
```

Comment: @raj can you tell any changes to be done

Comment: Add `configChanges` within your activity tag of android manifest file, refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701149/configchanges-work-in-android-4-and-2-2/20701191#20701191

Comment: have you check answer?

Comment: @SanketKachhela Yes, But still my application was crashing..

Comment: I got the same issue suddenly, i uninstalled and re-installed the application it started to work fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leak comes because you are keeping reference of activity after it destroyed also so use

```
if(progressDialog !=null)
{
    progressDialog = null;
}
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading data, please wait...");
```

**OR**

use this it will help

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSubmitNow:
        // Submit now

        // Sample upload image
        UploadImage.uploadImage("testimage");

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            // called before execution // main/UI thread
            protected void onPreExecute() {


             progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignOut_Activity.this);
             progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading data, please wait...");  

            progressDialog.show();
            };

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Submit the store data
                StoreData.postData(StoreList_Activity.storesList
                        .get(StoresListAdapter.Position));
                return null;
            }

            // on store data uploaded // main/UI thread
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                setSignOut();
                StoreList_Activity.storesList
                        .get(StoresListAdapter.Position).isSubmitted = true;
                SignOut_Activity.this.finish();
            };

        }.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why this Error...?

this error happen when you keep reference of unused activity

> Solution

remove reference of progress bar , dialog .....etc after use it .

by dismiss them or make them equal null

you can approach this when no longer need of it

**Recommended** put it in onStop

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
        if(_dialog.isShowing()){
            _dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(_dialog != null){
            _dialog = null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dismiss the `dialog` after its use, it won't let your application crash.

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 2):

use that code   `progressDialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you dismiss() the dialog, after dialog use and before any next background process to be initiated.